# Checking duplicated numbers in Array

Tags: c++, arrays

The function should check if there is any duplicated number but it's not working somehow.

anyone knows why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   int const size = 10;
   int arry[size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10};

   int i = 0;
   int k = 1;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       for (k = 1; k < size; k++)
       {
           if (arry[i] == arry[k])
           {
               cout << arry[i] << " " << arry[k] << endl;
               cout << "duplicate" << endl;
               return 0;
           }
       }
   }
   cout << "no duplicate" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "not working somehow" could mean anything.  What *is* it doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should skip when `i == k`.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   for (k = i+1; k < size; k++) // <-- either change HERE
   {
       if (i != k && arry[i] == arry[k])
       //  ^^^^^^ or HERE
       {
           cout << arry[i] << " " << arry[k] << endl;
           cout << "duplicate" << endl;
           return 0;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Since the code returns at the 1st pair of duplicated numbers found, this is not an issue. But the 1st change leads to less comparisons.

Comment: ah, didn't see that - my bad

Answer (score 0):

You're checking every combination twice - for example, you're comparing element 2 with element 5, and then 5 with 2. Aside from the fact that you're also checking an element with itself (which is what timrau's answer is guarding against), you're doing the same work twice.

So try

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     for (k = i + 1; k < size; k++)
```

instead.

Your approach still doesn't scale very well, it's essentially O(n^2). It would be faster to sort your array and then look for duplicate neighbors.

Comment: Also as @timrau mentions, it exits as soon as the first duplicate is detected

Comment: Doesn't matter. What if there are no duplicates, or if the duplicate is with the last check? This still doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach should be to sort the array first:

```
std::vector<int> a = {4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6};

std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    if (a[i - 1] == a[i]) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " " << a[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "duplicate" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
return 0;
```